# Update cloudformation stack from aws cli with SAM transform

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

When attempting to update a cloudformation stack in the aws cli:

```
aws --profile dev cloudformation update-stack --stack-name mystackname --template-body file://events-list.yaml
```

I get the following error

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: UpdateStack cannot be used with templates containing Transforms.
```

Because I am using the AWS Serverless transform for lambda function deployments

```
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
```

Is there a CLI way to execute this stack update or am I going to have to work on my APM in the GUI.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`deploy`](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) instead of [`update-stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html):

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
   --template-file serverless-output.yaml \
   --stack-name new-stack-name \
   --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

This command is necessary because [Transforms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-section-structure.html) need to be applied using [change sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-changesets.html), which the `deploy` command automates for you. Refer to [Working with Stacks that Contain Transforms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-section-structure.html#transform-section-structure-change-set) for further discussion:

> To create or update a stack with transforms, you must create a change set, and then execute it. A change set describes the actions AWS CloudFormation will take based on the processed template. During processing, AWS CloudFormation translates AWS SAM syntax into syntax that is defined by the transform. Processing can add multiples resources that you might not be aware of. For example, the specialized `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource adds an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) execution role and a Lambda function.
>
> To ensure that you're aware of all of the changes introduced by transforms, AWS CloudFormation requires you to use change sets. [...]
>
> If you use the AWS CLI, you can use the `package` and `deploy` commands to reduce the number of steps for launching stacks with transforms.

Answer (score 2):

Try with deploy instead of update-stack

aws cloudformation deploy \
   --template-file serverless-output.yaml \
   --stack-name new-stack-name \
   --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM

Comment: Sure, added an answer with references to additional documentation on the difference between the two commands.